# Flink CLI throws exception on EMR on a yarn cluster

Tags: apache-flink

After moving my enviornment from standalone cluster to yarn EMR cluster, I have been running into issues after with the flink cli commands when a job is running for a long time. Running `flink list` on the CLI I will get an exception thrown:

```
    > bin/flink list
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/flink-1.6.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
    Waiting for response...

    ------------------------------------------------------------
     The program finished with the following exception:

    org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Failed to retrieve job list.
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.listJobs(CliFrontend.java:438)
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$list$0(CliFrontend.java:420)
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runClusterAction(CliFrontend.java:979)
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.list(CliFrontend.java:417)
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1047)
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1120)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1120)
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted.
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$5(FutureUtils.java:213)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.lambda$submitRequest$1(RestClient.java:276)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:121)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:327)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:343)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:943)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
            ... 17 more
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:325)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
            ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
            ... 11 more
```

The job itself, as well as yarn, seem to be fine, there is no issue there.  I am unsure of the time it takes for this to happen, I have some jobs running for about a week with no problems, but usually after 2+ weeks the exception will occur at some point. I am currently running version 1.6.0.

I am not sure would logs would be useful in this case, but would be happy to provide anything I can in order to solve this problem.

Thank you

Update with logs:

```
    018-11-28 17:01:52,368 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,369 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -  Starting Command Line Client (Version: 1.6.0, Rev:ff472b4, Date:07.08.2018 @ 13:31:13 UTC)
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,369 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -  OS current user: hadoop
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,790 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -  Current Hadoop/Kerberos user: hadoop
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,790 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -  JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM - Oracle Corporation - 1.8/25.181-b13
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,790 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -  Maximum heap size: 7150 MiBytes
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,790 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -  JAVA_HOME: /etc/alternatives/jre
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,792 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -  Hadoop version: 2.8.3
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,792 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -  JVM Options:
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,792 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -     -Dlog.file=/home/hadoop/flink-1.6.0/log/flink-hadoop-client.log
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,792 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/hadoop/flink-1.6.0/conf/log4j-cli.properties
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,792 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:/home/hadoop/flink-1.6.0/conf/logback.xml
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,792 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -  Program Arguments:
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,792 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       -     list
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,794 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,797 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, localhost
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,797 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,797 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.size, 20480m
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,797 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.size, 20480m
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,797 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.memory.fraction, 0.9
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,797 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 1
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,797 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,798 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: state.backend, rocksdb
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,798 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: state.backend.fs.checkpointdir, s3://bucket/checkpoint
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,798 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: state.checkpoints.dir, s3://bucket/checkpoint
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,798 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: rest.port, 8081
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,798 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: web.timeout, 60000
    2018-11-28 17:01:52,798 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: akka.ask.timeout, 60s
    2018-11-28 17:01:53,029 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.security.modules.HadoopModule        - Hadoop user set to hadoop (auth:SIMPLE)
    2018-11-28 17:01:53,051 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       - Running 'list' command.
    2018-11-28 17:01:53,082 WARN  org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration                  - Config uses deprecated configuration key 'jobmanager.rpc.address' instead of proper key 'rest.address'
    2018-11-28 17:01:53,256 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient                      - Rest client endpoint started.
    2018-11-28 17:01:53,418 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       - Waiting for response...
    2018-11-28 17:02:53,492 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient                      - Shutting down rest endpoint.
    2018-11-28 17:02:53,493 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient                      - Rest endpoint shutdown complete.
    2018-11-28 17:02:53,495 ERROR org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend                       - Error while running the command.
    org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Failed to retrieve job list.
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.listJobs(CliFrontend.java:438)
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$list$0(CliFrontend.java:420)
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runClusterAction(CliFrontend.java:979)
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.list(CliFrontend.java:417)
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1047)
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1120)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
            at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1120)
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted.
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$5(FutureUtils.java:213)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.lambda$submitRequest$1(RestClient.java:276)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:504)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:483)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:121)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:327)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:343)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:943)
            at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
            ... 17 more
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:325)
            at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
            ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
            ... 11 more
```

Entrypoint + config logs

```
    Container: container_1541525872902_0001_01_000001 on compute.internal_8041
    =======================================================================================================
    LogType:jobmanager.log
    Log Upload Time:Thu Nov 29 20:13:10 +0000 2018
    LogLength:12837590
    Log Contents:
    2018-11-06 18:26:25,585 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2018-11-06 18:26:25,586 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Starting YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint (Version: 1.6.0, Rev:ff472b4, Date:07.08.2018 @ 13:31:13 UTC)
    2018-11-06 18:26:25,586 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  OS current user: yarn
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,007 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Current Hadoop/Kerberos user: hadoop
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,007 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM - Oracle Corporation - 1.8/25.181-b13
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,007 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Maximum heap size: 13653 MiBytes
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,007 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,008 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Hadoop version: 2.8.3
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,008 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  JVM Options:
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,008 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Xmx15360m
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,008 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dlog.file=/var/log/hadoop-yarn/containers/application_1541525872902_0001/container_1541525872902_0001_01_000001/jobmanager.log
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,008 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dlogback.configurationFile=file:logback.xml
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,008 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -     -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,008 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         -  Program Arguments: (none)
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,010 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,011 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,013 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - YARN daemon is running as: hadoop Yarn client user obtainer: hadoop
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,015 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: state.backend.fs.checkpointdir, s3://bucket/checkpoint
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,016 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: web.timeout, 60000
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,016 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: high-availability.cluster-id, application_1541525872902_0001
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,016 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, localhost
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,016 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,016 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: rest.port, 8081
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,016 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: internal.cluster.execution-mode, NORMAL
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,016 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.memory.fraction, 0.9
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,016 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,016 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 1
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,017 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: state.backend, rocksdb
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,017 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: akka.ask.timeout, 60s
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,017 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.size, 20480m
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,017 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.size, 20480m
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,017 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: state.checkpoints.dir, s3://bucket/checkpoint
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,031 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.clusterframework.BootstrapTools      - Setting directories for temporary files to: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541525872902_0001
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,046 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Starting YarnSessionClusterEntrypoint.
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,046 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Install default filesystem.
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,108 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.security.modules.HadoopModule        - Hadoop user set to hadoop (auth:SIMPLE)
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,125 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Initializing cluster services.
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,131 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Trying to start actor system at compute.internal:40607
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,612 INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger                                  - Slf4jLogger started
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,706 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                          - Starting remoting
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,804 INFO  akka.remote.Remoting                                          - Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://flink@compute.internal:40607]
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,813 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - Actor system started at akka.tcp://flink@compute.internal:40607
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,838 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                      - Created BLOB server storage directory /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541525872902_0001/blobStore-b4eb7331-9ac8-4fc9-ab1f-64f6a9c8173f
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,842 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServer                      - Started BLOB server at 0.0.0.0:32901 - max concurrent requests: 50 - max backlog: 1000
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,857 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.metrics.MetricRegistryImpl           - No metrics reporter configured, no metrics will be exposed/reported.
    2018-11-06 18:26:26,860 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.FileArchivedExecutionGraphStore  - Initializing FileArchivedExecutionGraphStore: Storage directory /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1541525872902_0001/executionGraphStore-0b405259-cc50-4332-93dc-847b92071699, expiration time 3600000, maximum cache size 52428800 bytes.
    2018-11-29 20:13:10,717 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.entrypoint.ClusterEntrypoint         - RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM. Shutting down as requested.
```

Comment: The client and the cluster entrypoint logs would indeed be helpful for further debugging. If you can upgrade to Flink 1.6.2, then you will receive better error messages on the client.

Comment: Added logs, as of right I can't update to 1.6.2, but will work toward that update eventually.

Comment: Could you also add the logs of the cluster entrypoint?

Comment: Added the entrypoint logs as well as some initial configuration logs